# Presenting a UIViewController from an embedded ViewController keeping its bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I try to present a ViewController modally from a parent ViewController that's already embedded in a UIView. But whenever I try presenting it, it just pops over the entire window. I want it to be equally sized as its parent. I do not need an animation for the transition. The only thing that worked so far is to again add it's view manually and manipulate the constraints via auto layout. Therefore I would present the controller by hiding its corresponding view. But compared to present that seems more like a workaround than a solution. So far I tried some options on modalPresentationStyle, but none of them seem to work for me. Glad for any help.
Cheers!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var viewController: ParentViewController = {
        let viewController = ParentViewController()
        
        return viewController
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75).isActive = true
        containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.75).isActive = true
        
        viewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        viewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        viewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        viewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}

class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ button: UIButton) {
        let childController = UIViewController() // This View Controller should fit it´s parents size. Instead it´s just presented normally and fits the window
        
        present(childController, animated: false)
    }
}
```

- Edit
  Derived from the community answers I implemented following solution:

  extension UIViewController {

  ```
   func open(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, in view: UIView? = nil, animated: Bool, duration: TimeInterval = 0.25, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

       viewControllerToPresent.view.isHidden = true

       open(viewControllerToPresent, in: view)

       if animated {
           viewControllerToPresent.view.alpha = 0.0
           viewControllerToPresent.view.isHidden = false

           UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
               viewControllerToPresent.view.alpha = 1.0
           } completion: { (_) in
               completion?()
           }
       }
       else {
           viewControllerToPresent.view.isHidden = false
           completion?()
       }
   }

   func open(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, in view: UIView? = nil) {
       let parentView = view ?? self.view!

       addChild(viewControllerToPresent)

       viewControllerToPresent.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       parentView.addSubview(viewControllerToPresent.view)
       viewControllerToPresent.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
       viewControllerToPresent.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
       viewControllerToPresent.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
       viewControllerToPresent.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

       viewControllerToPresent.didMove(toParent: self)
   }

   func close(animated: Bool, duration: TimeInterval = 0.25, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

       if animated {
           UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
               self.view.alpha = 0.0
           } completion: { (_) in
               self.close()
               completion?()
           }
       }
       else {
           close()
           completion?()
       }
   }

   func close() {
       view.removeFromSuperview()
       willMove(toParent: nil)
       removeFromParent()
   }
  ```

  }

Comment: childController fits the window because it doesn't know limits. You call just present so its working like normal controller. You add parent view controller limits in your code.

Comment: No that's not a workaround, it's fine

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! I just wasn't sure about that.